# how to change for the format for the blog archives?

Tags: wordpress

Now the wordpress is displaying the blog archives as following

```
Janauary 2012
```

But I want this

```
Jan (2)
```

where 2 is the total number of posts in the  month of January.
How will I do this?

Comment: what template are you using? Do you know how to modify (or create) a template? You need to modify your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the template and replace this `<?php the_time('F Y'); ?>` with this `<?php the_time('M'); ?> (<?php $current_month = date('m'); $count = get_posts("monthnum=$current_month" ); echo count($count); ?>)` and it should work.

WordPress links to archives using the "m" argument to index.php with the year first and the month second. So, for example, January 2012 would be `index.php?m=201201`. So, to link this, we need to create the link like this:

`<a href="/index.php?m=<?php echo date('Ym'); ?>"> ... </a>`

Comment: It works but it is not click able. I want to it as a link when I click on it, it will display the posts of that month.

Comment: Ok, I added how to create the link, let me know if that works and if you have any other questions!